# Where can I find LEGO-like building plans for Minecraft?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I like to build stuff in Minecraft, but I'm not the most creative person. I had the same problem with LEGO, but still had fun building stuff from these building plans. Those also gave me ideas which could fuel my lacking creativity after a bit.

Is there anything like the building plans that come with the LEGO boxes for Minecraft? A site where I can find good step by step plans which are clear and easy to follow?

Comment: You could always play around with [Minecraft Legos!](http://lego.cuusoo.com/ideas/view/4038)

Comment: @RavenDreamer - I was just about to post the same thing!

Comment: Svish, did I answer your question?

Answer (score 9):

Youtube is your friend. It's the best place to find out how to make structures, or at least get inspiration.

Here is an [example](http://www.youtube.com/watch?feature=player_embedded&v=eAEmqtjlRQw) of a house building tutorial.

Otherwise there is [minedraft](http://minedraft.net/) for 2D schematics drawings. I don't know if there is a library of minedraft schematics though.

[image: A schematic]

Above is an example of a schematic.

Answer (score 4):

MCEdit has a feature to save/load .schematic files.  If you [look](http://www.planetminecraft.com/resources/projects/) [around](http://www.mcschematics.com/) [the](http://www.minecraftforum.net/forum) [internets](http://www.google.ca/), you should be able to find plenty of people sharing what they have made in this format.  This, however requires MCEdit...

The other format I've seen things shared in is as saved worlds, which simply requires minecraft.  Again, search forums for them, there's lots out there.